# Tool to remove faucet?

Tags: tools, sink

I am VERY green too DIY work but I am trying to learn :)

I am trying to install new sink faucets and I am stuck on removing my old handles. The image below is from under the sink.

I cant reach the nuts that attach the handles to the sink and the little pipe sticking out the side of these make it so I cannot use the EZ Change Faucet tool. Not to mention these are too big to fit in there anyway.

I am hoping for some suggestion on how to get these off!

Full size Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiVZY.jpg

[image]

edit: i have a basin wrench but it does not fit around the nut because the sink and the wood frame are too close to the nut. is my only option breaking it?

Comment: loosen the nut all the way to the black plastic ... then lift up the threaded tube ... there may be a clip or a screw at the top end

Comment: I cant reach that nut on top to loosen it. It is in a recessed spot making it impossible to reach with any tool that i have. any recommendations? thanks so much @jsotola

Comment: take the picture to your local plumbing store, or a tool rental place, and ask for a tool ....

Comment: A basin wrench is what you need to reach those nuts. https://www.lowes.com/pd/IRWIN-11-in-Basin-Wrench/1000668439 - a new and improved basin wrench https://mechanical-hub.com/ridgid-basin-wrench/

Comment: @AlaskaMan thanks so much. I have a basin wrench but i cant fit it in there. the sink sits in a recessed wood frame and i cant fit the basin wrench between the nut and the frame. any other suggestions? thanks again!

Comment: Have you explored the possibility that there's another nut on top of the counter?

Comment: @AlaskaMan answers go down there vvv

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I have taken apart as much of the top as I can, I dont see any more nuts.

Comment: The link posted by @Alaska Man has the wrench you need.

Comment: @all i have a basin wrench but it does not fit around the top nut. there isnt enough space between the nut and the sink or sink frame.

Comment: Noting that you are "very green to DIY" and _not_ noting that you'd already tried a basin wrench led many to assume you _didn't_ have one or even know what it was. That's why it's important to include as many details as possible in your questions, to avoid recommendations for things that you've already tried and the potential insult because we _don't_ know you've tried it already.

Answer (score 1):

If the space is too tight to get a basin wrench in then it's possible that the plumber installed the faucet onto the basin *before* the bowl was put into place. After all, it's much easier to work on top of the cabinet than it is to work underneath.

You may want to look into removing the counter top from the cabinet, or the basin from the counter top to get at removing this.

Answer (score 0):

I've used vise grips with great success when dealing with similar problems like yours. Once the nut is loose it can be hand spun off. If the faucet is going to the trash the nut can be cut, but as a last resort. If you do decide to cut start below the nut but above the cross/supply piece (?). Once that is removed use a deep socket to unscrew the nut (15/16ths ?).